# Page doesn't load on redirect reactjs + redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am trying to redirect a user after login to home page, the redirect happens (this I know because the url changes and I go to a new page), but the content of the page doesn't load. I keep on getting this error

`Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/index"`

Here's my code for Login.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import '../App.css';
import 'whatwg-fetch';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { loginUser } from './../store/actions/loginActions';
import { Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class Login extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
 Email: '', Password: '', isloggedin: false
};

this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

 handleChange(event) {
 this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
 }

handleSubmit(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
this.props.loginUser(this.state)
}

render() {
  const { authError, token } = this.props;
if(token) return <Redirect to="/index" />  // I'm telling it to redirect if the state has a token
return (
    <div className="Background">
      <Card
        title="Login"
        style={{ width: 400 }}
       >
        <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">
         <Form.Item>
             <Input prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} name="Email" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
         </Form.Item>
         <Form.Item>
             <Input prefix={<Icon type="lock" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} type="password" name="Password" onChange={this.handleChange} />
         </Form.Item>
         <Form.Item>
       <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" disable='notloggedin' className="login-form-button">
         Log in
       </Button>
     </Form.Item>
   </Form>
     <div>
     { authError ? <p> { authError } </p> : null }
   </div>
      </Card>
    </div>
     );
   }
   }

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
authError: state.auth.authError,
 token: state.auth.token
  }
 }

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
 return {
loginUser: (data) => dispatch(loginUser(data))
  }
 }

   export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)      (Login));
```

My action is:

```
export const loginUser = (data) => {
return (dispatch, getState) => {
 fetch(url, {
    credentials: 'include',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(data)})
    .then(res => { if (res.ok) {
       return res.json() }
       else {
         return Promise.reject({
          status: res.status,
          statusText: res.statusText
        })
       }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
       dispatch({type: 'LOGIN_USER', value: response.AccessToken });
     })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({type: 'LOGIN_USER_FAILED', err });
    })
 }
};
```

and my App.js is

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Login from './components/Login';
import Home from './components/Home';

 class App extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
  <div className="App">
    <header className="App-header">
      <h3 className="App-logo"> App Load </h3>
    </header>
    <BrowserRouter>
   <Switch>
     <Route path="/" component={Login} />
     <Route path="/index" component={Home} />
   </Switch>
 </BrowserRouter>
```

);}}

```
export default App;
```

Could anyone please let me know if they see any reason as to why the redirect is working but not loading the page components? I'll really appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

try to wrap you whole App component into BrowserRouter

Comment: I shifted this `<Route path="/" component={Login} />` to the bottom of my routes and it worked. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 0):

I shifted this `<Route path="/" component={Login} />` to the bottom of my routes in App.js and it worked.